# Use twice ? in URL

Tags: .htaccess, url

I want create `url` simple below

```
http://test.com/name/new/?market=en
```

> htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^name/(.*)$ name.php?params=$1 [NC]
```

If use `print_r($_GET)` not result correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Query String Append](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa) flag:

```
RewriteRule ^name/(.*)$ name.php?params=$1 [QSA,NC]
```